# How to delete an item from ExpandableListView on long click with a ContextMenuItemSelected?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview, android-contextmenu

I am trying to delete an item from an ExpandableListView using a context menu. I am running into a null pointer exception. Please help me solve this issue. Below is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.deleteItem:
                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                    int position = info.position;
                    //this is my ArrayList                    
                    postList.remove(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Deleted an item", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case R.id.editItem:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: "I am running into a null pointer exception" then check the NPE. What does it say? Try to solve it!

Comment: The item.getMenuInfo is returning null since I'm using a custom adapter. I won't be able to know the position of the item selected in the listview without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of ContextMenuInfo is wrong, items in Expandablelistview have 2 position values,

```
    ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListView.ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
    int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that glaring error! Solved the issue